# How do I set a Svelte Component's event listener and inner HTML for slot dynamically via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

JavaScript:

```
    const dispatchEvent = createEventDispatcher();
    let dialog: Dialog;
```

HTML

```
<Dialog bind:this={dialog} on:close={() => {dispatchEvent("deletedPost", postIndex)}} modal={true} open={false}>
    ... Here I want to insert some HTML to be used in the slot of the "Dialog" component.
</Dialog>
```

My question is, how do I set the `on:close` and the inner HTML dynamically via JS?

I have this demand because this `Dialog` component should be reused for multiple purposes by its parent component. Sometimes it displays info about a post has been created, sometimes deleted, sometimes edited and so on.

And each of the cases requires different content in the component as well as a different handler for the `close` event emitted by the `Dialog`.

Should I use something like

```
dialog.$on = handlerFunction;
// I didn't find a possible property for setting HTML though
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is no way to programmatically interact with the slots (unless you want to investigate the Svelte internals and rely on implementation details which may change).

Either pass in a full component via the props (which can be rendered using `<svelte:component>`), insert only text or use `{@html}` to render HTML content (which is not recommended for security reasons).

(The syntax for the events is `dialog.$on('close', event => ...)` as detailed in the [client-side API section](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api).)

---

Example for all mentioned property types:

```html
<!-- Dialog.svelte -->
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    export let open = true;
    export let component = null;
    export let text = null;
    export let html = null;
    
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    $: dispatch(open ? 'open' : 'close');
</script>

<div>
    <h2>Dialog</h2>
    {#if component}
        <svelte:component this={component} />
    {/if}
    {#if text}
        {text}
    {/if}
    {#if html}
        {@html html}
    {/if}
    
    <div><button on:click={() => open = false}>Close</button></div>
</div>
```

Usage:

```js
// ...
import Content from './Content.svelte';
const d = new Dialog({
    // ...
    props: { text: 'Hello world' },
});
// or
const d = new Dialog({
    // ...
    props: { html: '<input placeholder="Text here"/>' },
});
// or
const d = new Dialog({
    // ...
    props: { component: Content },
});

d.$on('close', () => d.$destroy());
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d7eaa8474bea49589eab95215d30fd90?version=3.52.0)

As noted, `@html` is dangerous and ideally should only be used with XSS sanitization in place.